# Looking at a specific part of an image when processing an image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, crop

while doing image processing, i want to use specific part of an image for better performance.

for example "check only 10 percent when matching images, instead of the entire image"

the following code is taking two images. It prints the RGB values of all pixels when I print the parameters. I just want to send the parameters of the ten percent on the side I want.

```cpp
Mat TopImageMatchesAndHomography(Mat imageMatchInTop1, Mat imageMatchInTop2)
{
    if (!imageMatchInTop1.data || !imageMatchInTop2.data)
    {
        std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl;
    }
    m_FeatureDetectorTop = xfeatures2d::SURF::create(m_MinimumHessian, 4, 2, false, true);
    m_FeatureDetectorTop->detectAndCompute(imageMatchInTop1, cv::Mat(), m_FirstImageKeyPointsTop, m_FirstImageDescriptorsTop);
    m_FeatureDetectorTop->detectAndCompute(imageMatchInTop2, cv::Mat(), secondImageKeyPointsTop, secondImageDescriptorsTop);
}
```

```cpp
float WrapperCalculateBM_TL()
{
    roiBM_TL = labIm[m_IndiceTopLeft](cv::Rect(500, 500, 100, 100));
    return (cv::videostab::calcBlurriness(roiBM_TL)) * 1000;
}

float WrapperCalculateBM_TR()
{
    roiBM_TR = labIm[m_IndiceTopRight](cv::Rect(500, 500, 100, 100));
    return (cv::videostab::calcBlurriness(roiBM_TR)) * 1000;
}
```

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Comment: The language is c++, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it is c++.